# Description of a line bundle of order $r$ as a $\mu_r$-bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety, and let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$ of order $r$, that is $L^{\otimes r}\simeq \mathcal{O}_X$.

**Question:** Is it true that as a principal $\mathbb{C}^*$-bundle, $L$ has reduction of its structure group to $\mu_r:=\{\xi^r=1\}\subset\mathbb{C}^*$? In other words, can $L$ be viewed as a $\mu_r$-bundle?

I think one direction is OK: if $L$ is a $\mu_r$-bundle, then its transition functions $g_{ij}$ take values in $\mu_r$, and hence the $r$-tensor power will have transition function $g_{ij}^r=1$.

But I'm having difficulty seeing the other direction; namely if $L^r=\mathcal{O}_X$ then it is a  $\mu_r$-bundle. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does it say about a line bundle when the transition functions are identically $1$? You will get an equivalence "the structure group can be reduced to $\mu_r$ if and only if $L^{\otimes r}$ is ...", but "..." will not be $\mathcal{O}_X$, but something more rigid.

Comment: @Thorgott : If the transition functions are 1 then the bundle is trivial. But I don't see how it helps. If $L^r=\mathcal{O}_X$, I can deduce that the transition functions $g_{ij}$ satisfy $g_{ij}^r=f_i/f_j$ for some invertible functions $f_i, f_j$. After this I am stuck. Could you please elaborate on your hint?

Comment: So a *necessary* condition for reducing the structure group of $L$ to $\mu_r$ is that $L^{\otimes r}$ is trivial. Unless $\mathcal{O}_X$ is trivial, trying to get anything from the hypothesis that $L^{\otimes r}=\mathcal{O}_X$ is thus hopeless... What you can say, however, is the converse: if $L^{\otimes r}$ is tirival, then the structure group of $L$ can  be reduced to $\mu_r$. Just reverse your argument. This equivalence works for line bundles over any topological space. The truth of the matter is just that reducing the structure group to $\mu_r$ has little to do with $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which topology you use.

Line bundles on $X$ are classified by $H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$, so line bundles with the property $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes r}\simeq \mathcal{O}_X$ are classified by
$$
\mathrm{Ker}(H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m)\xrightarrow{r}H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m)).
$$
On the other hand, $\mu_r$-torsors on $X$ are classified by $H^1(X,\mu_r)$, and a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ arises from a $\mu_r$-torsor if and only if $[\mathcal{L}]\in H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is in the image of
$$
H^1(X,\mu_r)\to H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m).
$$
Therefore your question is equivalent to whether the sequence
$$
H^1(X,\mu_r)\to H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m)\xrightarrow{r}H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m)
$$
is exact.

In the analytic or étale topology, the answer is **YES**.
It follows from the exact sequence of (analytic or étale) sheaves called the Kummer sequence:
$$
1\to \mu_r\to \mathbb{G}_m\xrightarrow{r} \mathbb{G}_m\to  1\quad\text{(exact)}.
$$
However, in the Zariski topology the answer becomes **NO**; the exactness on the right of the Kummer sequence is no longer true.
The sheaf $\mu_r$ is (non-canonically) isomorphic to the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$, so it is flasque in the Zariski topology and hence $H^1(X,\mu_r)=0$.
Therefore non-trivial line bundles can never be reduced to a $\mu_r$-torsor.